# How to Programmatically Move android device gmail inbox items

Tags: android, gmail

I have requirement to show number of **unread gmail counts** in my application,Well i found solution for that requirement but here when i tapped on **unread gmail counts button** i want to open device gmail application inbox message,Is this is possible if possible can some one help me with some code.

Answer (score 0):

I usually open Gmail with the following code in my apps:

```
Intent gmail= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mailClient.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivity");
startActivity(gmail);
```

Handle the manifest file and the dependencies.

In manifest file enable access to Gmail's content provider as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_CONTENT_PROVIDER" />
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: is this is not possible to show gmail inbox messages in our application listview?

Answer (score -1):

Read [Gmail API of Android](https://developers.google.com/gmail/android/), for gmail access. Otherthan, gmail app no longer supports access such as you need Refer link https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/08/gmail-gone-risk-undocumented-apis.html.

For open Gmail App you can use this .

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.an‌​droid.gm"); startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: is this is not possible to show gmail inbox messages in our application listview?

Comment: Not possible to show unread count of gmail messages , there are some changes in gmail api . First you have to go through with gmail api .